# Limit question involving tail of power series of exponential function.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

After some calculations, I've arrived at a small problem that I can't seem to resolve. Essentially, how quickly one would need to approximate $e^n$ as $n$ gets large through its Taylor series so as to have a vanishing error:

What's a (relatively sharp) sequence of natural numbers $(a_n)$ increasing to $+\infty$ so that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(e^n-\sum_{k=0}^{a_n}\frac{n^k}{k!}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=a_n+1}^\infty\frac{n^k}{k!}=0\,?$$ Sharp meaning, we'd ideally like $a_n\to\infty$ as slowly as possible.

---

As Clement C suggests, we certainly would need $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{a_n}}{a_n!} = 0.$$ Or equivalently (by taking logs), $$a_n\log(n)-\sum_{j=1}^{a_n}\log(j)\to -\infty,$$ taking $a_n=cn$ and using the approximation $\sum_{j=1}^N\log(j)\sim N(\log(N)-1)$ yields $$cn\log(n)-cn\left(\log(cn)-1\right)\\=cn\left(\log(n)-\log(cn)+1\right)\to-\infty,$$
provided we take $c>e$. This provides a lower bound on $a_n$.

Comment: Well, for a start you definitely need the first term to go to zero, so $\left(\frac{n^{a_n+1}}{(a_n+1)!}\right)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$. That should give you a lower bound on $a_n$ (from back-of-the-envelope computations, linear in $n$?)

Comment: Stirling's formula: For $A>0$ we have  $|A!^{-1}(A/e)^A\sqrt {2\pi A}-1|<1/6A$ . Also , when $ n+1>x>0$ we have  $x^n/n!<$ $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}x^{n+j}/(n+j)!<$ $(x^n/n!) (\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(x/(n+1)^j=$ $(x^n/n!)(1-x/(n+1))^{-1}.$